# Теряются задачи

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rabbitmq, celery

Всем привет, использую в проекте Django, Celery и RabbitMQ. Заметил, что при большой нагрузке кол-во Processed не равно кол-ву Succeeded + Failed.

Например сейчас

```
Processed: 1598741
Succeeded: 1598591
Failed   : 1
Retried  : 0
```

Каждая таска создает объект в эластике, поэтому потеря задач также подтверждается разницей между кол-вом отправленных запросов и кол-вом объектов в эластике. Потерь примерно 1,5 процента. При этом я не могу явно отловить ошибку где-то в задачах. Пишу лог в файл (общий) и Centry (для ошибок). К примеру, вот я вижу этот Failed в сентри, а где еще 150 сообщений я не знаю.

Внутри задач я настроил запись в лог, чтобы регистрировать запуск каждой задачи и отследить в какой именно момент теряются они. К примеру мы имеем такие таски:

```
task1 - парсинг запроса
task2 - основная работа
task3 - запись результата
```

Task1 запускается из view, эта таска принимает некий набор объектов и в цикле запускает N задач task2, где N - это кол-во объектов в наборе. Каждая таска task2, после выполнения работы запускает task3.

Вот сообщения теряются между task2 и task3. Причем я могу посчитать и убедиться что task2 приняла верное кол-во объектов, а вот task3 была запущена уже меньшее кол-во раз.

Как мне выяснить причину?

PS: если чего-то не сказал, пишите, доскажу)

Настройки celery

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('network', Exchange('network'), routing_key='network', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10}),
    Queue('process_item', Exchange('prepare_objects'), routing_key='process_item', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10}),
    Queue('dispatch', Exchange('dispatch'), routing_key='dispatch', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10}),
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10}),
)
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {
    'api.tasks.task3': {'queue': 'network'},
    'api.tasks.task2': {'queue': 'process_item'},
    'api.tasks.task1': {'queue': 'dispatch'},
}
# Setup Celery Logger
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
LOGGING['handlers']['celery_file_handler'] = {
    'level': 'INFO',
    'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
    'formatter': 'verbose',
    'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'celery', '{}.log'.format(datetime.now().date())),
    'maxBytes': 1024000,
    'backupCount': 3,
}
LOGGING['loggers']['celery.tasks'] = {
    'handlers': ['celery_file_handler', 'console'],
    'level': 'INFO',
    'propagate': False
}
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://@rabbit:'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
# CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_RETRY_DELAY = 30
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_WORKER_MAX_MEMORY_PER_CHILD = 60_000 # 60 MB
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 120
CELERY_TASK_MAX_RETRIES = 10
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

Запуск celery

`python -m celery multi start --app=APP --pidfile=/tmp/%n.pid --logfile=/dev/null 50 -c 4 -Q:1-4 dispatch -Q:5-49 process_item,network -c:50 1 -Q:50 celery -E &&`

В работе сервер нагружен примерно на 80-95%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

итак, суть проблемы заключалась в слишком большом кол-ве работников. как только уменьшил их кол-во до 20 все стало работать отлично. я не знаю с чем это связано, было бы здорово если тот кто знает подсказал бы. или я позже постараюсь выбрать время чтобы разобраться.